# What happens if we pass a directory location to Node.js require function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have cloned [Express.js repo](https://github.com/strongloop/express) containing an Examples folder having Express.js different use cases. I opened the Hello World example and the code started with the following line

```
var express = require('../../');
```

I understand rest of the code in that file, but the line above is going over my head? I know `require` function is used to include a JS module in your project and one is supposed to pass the module name as argument to `require()` function, but in the case of the above statement, we are passing in a directory, what is it going to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing an `index.js` file that is located two folders after the current one.

Example:

[image]

So, if you have this on your `yourFile.js`

```
var something = require('../../');
```

You are making reference to your `index.js`.

It is exactly the same if you do something like this:

```
var something = require('../../index');
```

and both are exactly the same with this one (with `.js`, which is unnecessary in this case)

```
var something = require('../../index.js');
```

That happens because `index.js` is the default name.

You could read more [at nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) but the important part is quoted here:

> If there is no package.json file present in the directory, then
> Node.js will attempt to load an index.js or index.node file out of
> that directory. For example, if there was no package.json file in the
> above example, then require('./some-library') would attempt to load:
>
> ./some-library/index.js
>
> ./some-library/index.node

Answer (score 2):

It will load `index.js` if no filename is given.